# Como solucionar problema de varias id con mismo nombre

Tags: php, jquery, modal

Tengo la siguiente lista + modal.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');?>


<!-- ////////////////////// SI NO HAY empleados REGISTRADOS EN LA BASE DE DATOS MOSTRAR MENSAJE  ////////////////////////// -->
<?php if (count($resultado) <= 0) { ?>
  <h3 class="text-center"><?php echo $etiqueta_sin_registrar; ?></h3>
<?php } else { ?>
  <!-- ////////////////////// INICIO TABLA  ////////////////////////// -->
  <table class="table table-lg table-hover">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nombre</th>
        <th>Apellido</th>
        <th>CUIL</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
      <?php foreach ($resultado as $p): ?>

        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $p->nombre; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $p->apellido; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $p->cuil; ?></td>
          <td></td>
          <!-- ////////////////////// BOTONES  ABRIR MODAL ////////////////////////// -->
          <td>
            <a href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#blanc-user-<?php echo $p->cuil; ?>"><i class="fa fa-unlock" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <div class="modal fade" id="blanc-user-<?php echo $p->cuil; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <form method="post" class="formu" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>blanquear/<?php echo $p->cuil; ?>">
                      <div class="modal-header">Blanquear clave</div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <label for="pass">Contraseña: </label>
                                  <input type="password" name="pass" class="pass" id="pass">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <label for="pass2">Confirmar Contraseña: </label>
                                  <input type="password" name="pass2" class="pass2" id="pass2">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                          <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning btn-rounded btn-blanc">Blanquear</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                          </div>
                        </form>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </td>
          <!-- ////////////////////// FIN BOTONES  ABRIR MODAL ////////////////////////// -->
        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!-- ////////////////////// FIN TABLA  ////////////////////////// -->
  <?php if (count($resultado) > 0) {
    ?> <div class="d-flex justify-content-center bd-highlight mb-3">
      <?php  echo $pagination; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
  }

} ?>

  </div>
</div>
```

El problema esta en el modal, yo necesito tener los dos inputs con id para poder hacer la validacion correspondiente con Jquery.Validate:

```
$(".formu").validate({
        rules: {
            pass:{required:true,maxlength:250,},
            pass2:{
                required:true,
                equalTo:"#pass",
            }
        },
        errorClass: "mensajeerrorfondoazul",
                errorElement: "span",
    });
```

al formulario lo llamo con el class, pero los campos como se podria hacer referencia con class ?

Answer (score 1):

lo recomendable sería que hicieras un único modal y cuando selecciones para mostrarlo este se llene con los datos usando Ajax y te evitarías hacer un modal por cada elemento de tu lista.
En caso de seguir adelante de la manera que has descrito, puedes usar addClassRules.
Después de llamar a
$(.formu).validate()
Puedes agregarlas usando
jQuery.validator.addClassRules("miclase", {
required: true,
minlength: 2
});

https://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addClassRules/#namerules

Comment: Como seria la primer opción

Comment: Gracias! Pude resolverlo de la primer forma que me mencionabas!

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado :)